# Pandas DataFrame filtering || Keeping only consecutive elements of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, data-science

I have the following DataFrames

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [201, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202, 203, 203, 203],
                   'b': [  1,   2,   3,   5,   1,   2,   6,   1,   3,   4]})

df_filter = pd.DataFrame({'a': [      201,    202, 203],
                          'b': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]}).set_index('a')
```

they look like:

```
>>> df
     a  b
0  201  1
1  201  2
2  201  3
3  201  5
4  202  1
5  202  2
6  202  6
7  203  1
8  203  3
9  203  4
>>>
>>> df_filter
             b
a             
201  [1, 2, 3]
202     [1, 2]
203        [1]
```

I want to filter the df, using the df_filter. Namely, I want to keep for each element of 'a', the elements of the corresponding list in 'b'.

Wanted result:

```
>>> df_filtered
     a  b
0  201  1
1  201  2
2  201  3
4  202  1
5  202  2
7  203  1
```

Also, I actually want to keep only the consecutive elements of 'b' for each of the elements on 'a'. I now can produce 'df_filter' and filter with that, but any suggestion to do this easier whould be more than welcome.

Comment: Try not to use the name filter for a dataframe, that is a special name in python and a DataFrame method

Comment: Thanks for the comment. These, of course, are not the actual dataframes; I kept it simple. But, yes you 're right. I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for pandas `0.25+` - convert lists to rows by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and then `merge` by default inner join (columns names are same, so `on` parameter is omit):

```
df = df_filter['b'].explode().reset_index().merge(df)
print (df)
     a  b
0  201  1
1  201  2
2  201  3
3  202  1
4  202  2
5  203  1
```

Or [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) if input is 2 columns `DataFrame`:

```
df_filter = pd.DataFrame({'a': [      201,    202, 203],
                       'b': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]})

df = df_filter.explode('b').merge(df)
print (df)
     a  b
0  201  1
1  201  2
2  201  3
3  202  1
4  202  2
5  203  1
```

EDIT: For avoid reset to default index values use `reset_index` with `set_index`:

```
df = df_filter.explode('b').merge(df.reset_index()).set_index('index')
print (df)
         a  b
index        
0      201  1
1      201  2
2      201  3
4      202  1
5      202  2
7      203  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Almost! Notice that I want to keep the indexes of the original df.

Comment: Thanks again. This is perfect. Any ideas on how to keep only the consecutive elements of 'b', without making the intermediate step with df_filter?

Comment: @ThanasisMattas - yop, I need some time

Comment: @ThanasisMattas - Do you think first group of consecutive values? `df = df[df.groupby('a')['b'].diff().fillna(0).replace(1, 0).groupby(df['a']).cumsum().eq(0)]` ? Can you check it?

Comment: @ jezrael this works. It's a bit nightmare for anyone to understand though; I 'll try to break it a bit. Also, I think your edit above does not work.

Comment: @ThanasisMattas - what is unclear, I can try explain better.

Comment: I can understand it, but it definetly does not complement readability (imagine putting the real names, too). Anyway, this works for me. Thank you a lot!